# a few questions before updating to 13.04

Tags: 13.04, ati

About a month ago I updated my computer through the update manager. It completely broke my system. I decided to remove ubuntu and try again another time. So now I reinstalled ubuntu fresh with 12.04.

I'm wondering if I should attempt the update with this fresh install or just do a fresh install of ubuntu 13.04?

I'm also wondering if there is a graphics card issue between ubuntu and my laptop. I have an hp dv7-6135dx. It has hybrid graphics capability but I have not and will not mess with these drivers because everytime I do my graphics break.

I'm just wondering if I do a fresh install will my system function with the default open source driver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well now that you have a fresh install of 12.04, you need to upgrade to Ubuntu 12.10 then to Ubuntu 13.04. You can only skip releases if you are upgrading from an LTS release to another LTS.

Now that being said,  and you do want 13.04, I would recommend a fresh install of it, but before you install it, or even update, download 13.04, and try it without installing, to see if all your hardware is working OK.  At that point if all is OK, then go ahead with the fresh install.

**Note**:  Make sure that you backup any information that you need before choosing either way.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I will go ahead and do this